# Do valve adjusters ever go bad?

Tags: honda, valve, odyssey

Do the top screw parts of the valve adjustment screw ever go bad?

Doing a valve adjustment on 2005 Honda Odyssey.  On a few valves, the part that you adjust does not feel right. It is either too loose and if I move it a hair it is way too tight, can't even get the gauge to pass through.  It feels like the valve end and the adjuster screw are not flat and slight turn makes a sharp pinch point.  Is this possible?  Could not find anything on the web about it.

Adjustment is supposed to happen around 100,000 miles, don't know if it was done or not.  Current mileage is over 150,000.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Try to turn the engine 720° (two turns of the crank) and try the adjustment again. This may change the aspect of it *just a little bit* which might allow it to adjust.